# VTL Scripting- Splitting a variable string into two variables

Tags: velocity, vtl

I have a Script written in the VTL that contains a variable(customer.name) that pulls in a combined string with a name and then a number attached to it. I am currently trying to split the customer.name combined string into two new variables by using an array to get the correct output for each row in my table. How can I achieve this in VTL? I have two new variables initialized that I want to use for each part of the string. One to pull the number from the variable string and another to pull the name from the variable string.

#set($CustomerName =
#set($CustomerPartNumber =